# Is redis an efficient solution if I need to use a composite key and query on only part of that key often?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I am building a notification service and have a need for a datastore to store my notifications. I am considering using redis for this since the data is ephemeral in nature (time to live of a few days) and the volume shouldn't be too use (maybe a couple hundred thousand records at a given time, split across 20 or 30 thousand users)

My service is using a java springboot backend and I am currently setting up the data and repository classes. The composite key for my notifications is the following:

`userId:notificationType:notificaionId`

where userId is the user this notification is being sent to, notificationType is the type (currently have 5 or 6 types), and notificationId will be the unique key.

I'm using a composite key because my understanding is that with redis you want to only ever query by keys, running queries on the value is not efficient. I suppose I could throw the userId and notificationType into the JSON that represent my value and put secondary indexes on them but is that really a good idea if I'm most often going to be querying by userId to fetch this data?

I'm running into some problems with the spring redis libraries and finding it difficult to figure out exactly how to translate my queries to code.

To populate my notification drawer in the UI I need to fetch all notifications for a given user. I ordered the values in my key so that the most broad value is first and they get more specific from there (userId -> notificationType -> notificationId).

The redis query would look like `KEYS [userId]*`

Based on everything I've been reading I know I should not be using the `KEYS` command in a production environment and the runtime doesn't seem great either.

I guess I'm wondering if I should still be considering redis as my datastore or move to something relational where I can set up better indexing and have more flexibility with my queries.

Answer (score -1):

## Two approaches

There's really two rational approaches you could take to managing something like this.

1. Make use of Redis' [Search And Query](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/) capability, and maintaining a notification index (presumably with userId and notificationId indexed)
2. Leverage [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/streams/), and storing your notifications as items in the stream that you can read in the context of a given consumer's consumer group

### Search and Query

The easiest way to use Search and Query in Spring is using [Redis OM Spring](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring), but essentially you would have a notifications index, and you would index both the userId and possibly the notification Id, depending on how you are marking the notifications as Read you might even just have the notification's timestamp be indexed and just sort on that. Let's say you do the later option:

```
FT.CREATE notifications PREFIX 1 notification: SCHEMA userId TAG timestamp NUMERIC SORTABLE
```

You could then insert your notifications, and if you want your notifications to be ephemeral (say they last a week), you could set them to expire after a week:

```
HSET notification:12345 userId 54321 notificationId 12345 timestamp 1706013995
EXPIRE notification:12345 604800
```

And then you can search for all notifications matching your users, who's timestamp is later than the most recently read notification for your user:

```
FT.SEARCH notifications "@userId:{54321} @timestamp:[170613800 inf]" SORTBY timestamp DESC
```

### Redis Streams

Redis Streams are an append-only log data structure, they allow you to add items (e.g. notifications) sequentially, and they allow you to trim those streams based off of the capacity of the stream, or timestamps. Each stream message consists of two things

1. The Stream Id which is in the format of `<millisecondsTime>-<sequenceNumber>`, generally you have Redis make this for you.
2. The payload of the stream messages is a series of key-value pairs for simplicity sake we'll just assume this is a single key `payload` with a single json value

You could create a stream per-user:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> XADD user:54321:notifications MINID ~ 1705409905955 * payload "{'name':'foo'}"
```

this will add a new notification for `user:54321`, and it will remove all notifications that are more than a week old.

Let's say that `1705409905955` happened to be the last time that `user:54321` read a notification, you could then read all the notifications since then with:

```
XREAD STREAMS user:54321:notifications 1705409905955
```

### Either should work

Both approaches should work pretty well, it all depends on your data, Search and Query is a bit more flexible in that you can edit the data (e.g. if you wanted to mark notifications as read or unread it would definitely be the way to go).